# Typescript 0.9 + Knockout: strange compiler errors

Tags: visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, typescript, web-essentials

I just upgraded my code to Typescript 0.9, updated the DefinitelyTyped definitions of Jquery, JqueryUI, Knockout, Knockout.Mapping and Knockout.Validation.

The code seemingly compiles, I see the correct output js files.

Yet VS underlines EVERY use of the `obs(value: T)` setter on `KnockoutObservable<T>` and `KnockoutObservableArray<T>`, saying I provided invalid type.

```
Error   27  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.  
Error   28  Could not select overload for 'call' expression.
```

I have about a 100 of these errors. When I try to type one in, the intellisense offers `(): T` and `(value: bool):void` for every type - yes, it's bool regardless of the T I specified. Is it a VS, a compiler or a WebEssentials bug? How do I make the ~100 errors disappear?

**EDIT (visual evidence):**
[image]
`lot.TimeOnServer` is a `KnockoutObservable<number>`, `data.TimeOnServer` is a `number`.

Yes, I have restarted vs+windows. The error persisted.

Comment: Could you post one of those lines VS is throwing a wobbly over?

Comment: @Anzeo: added example screenshot

Comment: @kingdango: what do you mean 'doesn't like naked lambdas'? This code compiles and runs correctly.

Comment: @kingdango: no, data.TimeOnServer is a `number`, as I mention in the post. It's an interface over json returned from the WebAPI backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this same issue. I haven't investigated *why* this is happening, but in my project after commenting out the last interface in knockout.validation.d.ts the errors go away. This will break your call to isValid for validation though.

```
interface KnockoutSubscribableFunctions {
  isValid: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
  isValidating: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
  rules: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutValidationRule>;
}
```

I added the following to get back the isValid function

```
interface KnockoutObservableBase {
    isValid: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;
    isValidating: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    rules: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutValidationRule>;
}
```